# Eclipse Android exceptions are hidden

Tags: android, eclipse

The code in my book created a NPE for me to see. But, when I open the logcat in ddms, I cannot see all the errors (it says 11 more). How do I see all the exceptions ? Please see the photo below -

[image]

**EDIT -** Image for full trace posted. Also posting text of trace by copy pasting.

Image -

[image]

```
D/QuizActivity(836): onCreate(Bundle) called
D/AndroidRuntime(836): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(836): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
E/AndroidRuntime(836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(836): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.updateQuestion(QuizActivity.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
E/AndroidRuntime(836):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: The actual errors to be shown in the above part it self. Please look that carefully for you error. You dont need the  11 more part for clearing your error.

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan - agree. But, how does one see the remaining errors ?

Comment: What is the need for showing that?

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan - No harm in knowing a little more, right ?

Comment: You need to click the line after "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" that line will take you to the code.

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan - that did not work. Question edited.

Comment: just double click on at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.updateQuestion(QuizActivity.java:47)

or
  at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:111)

if again fails just restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You dont usually need the whole stack trace, the main thing to look for is "caused by" message and the class(TAG) which is causing the exception

Comment: Its an NPE which I can see. But, I'd like to see the whole trace.

Comment: @Abby his need is not to determine the exception but to get the all exception printed in log cat.

Comment: @RenjithKrishnan - one more problem is that when I click the NPE exception in logcat, eclipse will not take me to the code which causes the error.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. printing Log.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString()) in the catch block. This should work

Comment: You need to click the line after "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" that line will take you to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **try catch block** and [Java Doc 
printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) to see the full stack trace.

```
try {
   // Expected Exception Rasing Line
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: one more problem is that when I click the NPE exception in logcat, eclipse will not take me to the code which causes the error

Comment: Dont click on the NPE ,Click on the line number which was causing the NPE..Hope it ll navigate

Comment: There is no line number - only time, pid, tid, application, tag, text columns in logcat. I can barely see some number in the Text column. Clicking that also does not work. :(

Comment: Click at this line **at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.updateQuestion(QuizActivity.java:47)**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44207/discussion-between-name-cant-be-displayed-and-trojan-zbot)